# How can I replace multiple rows simultaneously in a Python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with the following unique values in one of its columns.

```
   df['Gender'].unique()

   array(['Female', 'M', 'Male', 'male', 'm', 'Male-ish', 'maile',
   'Trans-female', 'Cis Female', 'something kinda male?', 'Cis Male',
   'queer/she/they', 'non-binary', 'Make', 'Nah', 'All', 'Enby',
   'fluid', 'Genderqueer', 'Androgyne', 'Agender', 'Guy (-ish) ^_^',
   'male leaning androgynous', 'Male ', 'Man', 'msle', 'Neuter',
   'queer', 'A little about you', 'Malr',
   'ostensibly male, unsure what that really means')]
```

As you can see, there are obvious cases where a row should be listed as 'Male' (I'm referring to the cases where 'Male' is misspelled, of course). How can I replace these values with 'Male' without calling the replace function ten times? This is the code I have tried:

```
x=0
while x<=11:
for i in df['Gender']:
    if i[0:2]=='Ma':
        print('Male')
    elif i[0]=='m':
        print('Male')
x+=1
```

However, I just get a print of a bunch of "Male".

Edit: I want to convert the following values to 'Male': 'M', 'male', 'm', 'maile', 'Make', 'Man', 'msle', 'Malr', 'Male '

Comment: Can you provide an expected output, because its not sure exactly which have to be converted to `Male`. For example `man` and the sentence.

Comment: For example the last sentence, which has `male` in it. Does the complete sentence has to be replaced by `Male`?

Comment: No. I'm not sure what to make of that one. I was thinking of just removing it. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list with all the nicknames of Male:

```
males_list = ['M', 'male', 'm', 'maile', 'Make', 'Man', 'msle', 'Malr', 'Male ']
```

And then replace them with:

```
df.loc[df['Gender'].isin(males_list), 'Gender'] = 'Male'
```

btw: There is always a better solution than looping the rows in `pandas`, not just in cases like this.

Comment: What if the word is in the middle of a sentence?

Comment: @Erfan Than he should specifically add it to the list, other wise 'not a male' or 'fe male' might also be included.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function as it allows you to create any custom logic. So for instance, by looking at your code, something like this would do the trick:

```py
def correct_gender(text):

    if text[0:2]=='Ma' or text[0]=='m':
        return "Male"

    return text

df["Gender"] = df["Gender"].map(correct_gender)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a more generalized approach. We can use regex to check if the word starts with `M` or has the letters `Ma` preceded by a whitespace, so we dont catch `Female`:

- `(?i)`: stands for ignore case sensitivity
- `?<=\s`: means all the words which start with `ma` and are preceded by a whitespace

```
df.loc[df['Gender'].str.contains('(?i)^M|(?<=\s)ma'), 'Gender'] = 'Male'
```

**Output**

```
                Gender
0               Female
1                 Male
2                 Male
3                 Male
4                 Male
5                 Male
6                 Male
7         Trans-female
8           Cis Female
9                 Male
10                Male
11      queer/she/they
12          non-binary
13                Male
14                 Nah
15                 All
16                Enby
17               fluid
18         Genderqueer
19           Androgyne
20             Agender
21      Guy (-ish) ^_^
22                Male
23                Male
24                Male
25                Male
26              Neuter
27               queer
28  A little about you
29                Male
30                Male
```